# JQuery not removing background image if .active class

Tags: jquery, css

i'm having trouble with jquery not removing a background image.

i'm using [Zurb's Foundation framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/) with deep-linking and have some code in this form (i've chopped out quite a bit of the html):

```
<div id="contentWrap">
  <section id="one" class="mixed">
    <a href="#">One</a>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </section>   
  <section id="two" class="mixed active">
    <a href="#">One</a>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

i'm using css to set #contentWrap with a background image but i only want the image to show when the first link is active.

i'm using this JQuery code:

```
// Add background image if #one clicked
$('#one a').click(function(){
  $("#contentWrap").css("background-image","url('xx.jpg')");
});

// Remove background image if #two clicked
$('#two a').click(function(){
  $("#contentWrap").css("background-image","none");
});

// Remove background image if #two has class of .active
if ( $("#two").hasClass("active") ) {
  $("#contentWrap").css("background-image","none")
};
```

if the page is loaded with the second tab active via deep-linking (i.e. xx.com/#two), the background image is still loaded.

i used to have this working but have since made several updates to the way the code is loaded on the (wordpress) site and am now using `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` to wrap all the other JS (which is working).

any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Leon, if the problem is solved, and my answer helped you, please accept as answer, if it didnt, explain why, and elaborate on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

if i got you right, when `two` div is active, only then the background should be removed?

```
// Remove background image if #two clicked
$('#two a').click(function(){
   // Remove background image if #two has class of .active
    if ( $("#two").hasClass("active") ) {
      $("#contentWrap").css("background-image","none")
    };
});
```

working jsfiddle: (changed `background-image` to `background`)
http://jsfiddle.net/Vvg5F/4/

Comment: and remove the last `if` since we moved it into the click.

Comment: thanks very much for the quick response Dementic but this doesn't seem to work if the page is loaded with the second tab active on page load. the background of #contentWrap is set to xx.jpg in the css file but should be cleared as soon as the page loads if the person has linked to tab 2 (#two). any ideas?

Comment: in that case, add to your original code another `if` like the last one, with `#one` as the selector

Comment: hi Dementic, i've tried that but it still doesn't work. could the issue be that the .active class is being applied after the background JS has already been run? if so, is there a way of delaying it till afterward?

Comment: it's being generated using Foundation's Section JS: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/section.html. can i message you the actual URL of the page?

Comment: you should add the code to the callback of the section.
send me the page link in pm and ill have a look.

Comment: sorry Dementic. this is going to sound really stupid but how do i pm on here? i don't have much reputation...

Comment: rafael at orielo .com